# Unable to load ViewController: CABTMIDILocalPeripheralViewController

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

Since iOS 8, Apple has made Midi via Bluetooth LE an option, for both Peripheral and Central Roles. As they suggest, adding a Peripheral ViewController is supposed to be as simple as including the following code, which I've done. This method is executed at the click of a UIbutton

```
CABTMIDILocalPeripheralViewController *midiPeripheralController = [[CABTMIDILocalPeripheralViewController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:midiPeripheralController animated:YES];
```

When executed, this returns the following error. How can I prevent this error?

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: 'Cannot remove an observer  for the key path "parentViewController" from  because it is not registered as an observer.'

Comment: I used these two lines in a test application and they worked fine. You need to look at what you have done prior to presenting this new view controller - in particular any KVO observers you have created or are attempting to clear

Comment: I've done nothing at all. I created a test project, added a single UIButton and an IBAction to connect the button to these two lines of code and I'm getting this error. Is using Storyboard perhaps a problem with these new ViewController classes?

Comment: Is your view embedded in a navigation controller?

Comment: Thanks Paulw. I started with a 'single view application,' which of course contains no navigationcontroller. I needed to add that manually to the Storyboard, connect it correctly and things are now working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

```
import UIKit
import CoreAudioKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var localPeripheralViewController:CABTMIDILocalPeripheralViewController?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        localPeripheralViewController = CABTMIDILocalPeripheralViewController()

    }

    @IBAction func local(sender: AnyObject) {
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(localPeripheralViewController!, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

when the `CABTMIDILocalPeripheralViewController` wants to dismiss it actually removes an predefined key `@"parentViewController"` which at that moment cant be removed cause it was not set, so it throws an exception. Meaning you have to add that observer yourself to avoid violation of the KVO programming. In example in objective-c with

```
-(void)yourActionOnSomeButton:(UIButton *)sender {
    // ... here is your build up code of the CABTMIDILocalPeripheralViewController

    // ... but before presenting the navController you add Observer yourself,
    // so it can be removed when dismissing or "done"
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
    popC.sourceView = button.superview;
    [popC addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"parentViewController" options:(NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew) context:nil];
    [self presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: didnt check for sideeffects, meaning you have to know what you are observing here and why its removed by the popOver and so on..